# What is the rule of pandas resample with rolling 30 minutes?

Tags: pandas, pandas-resample

I am trying to resample a kbars dataframe from 1 minute to 30 minutes. And I need a rolling window. However, it seems that's a fixed time frame.

For example, it's now 9:28 pm. The latest row of the reshape `data = df.resample('30min')` is 9:00 pm. That does not meet my needs. But it works if I change to `data = df.resample('29min')`. The latest row is 9:09 pm
So, what is the rule of resample?

Can I resample with a 30 minute rolling window?

The following is an example code to show the difference of resample 30m and 29m. Resample of 30 minutes is fixed on the clock, not a rolling window.

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

recent_hours = 2
date_index = pd.date_range(end=pd.to_datetime('now'), periods=recent_hours * 60 // 3.4, freq='3T')
# Create a sample DataFrame with random OHLC data
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'open': np.random.rand(len(date_index)),
    'high': np.random.rand(len(date_index)),
    'low': np.random.rand(len(date_index)),
    'close': np.random.rand(len(date_index))
}, index=date_index)

# The datetime index of sample_30m is precisely aligned with the half-hour and the top of every hour.
sample_30m = data.resample('30min').agg({
    'open': 'first',
    'high': 'max',
    'low': 'min',
    'close': 'last',
})

# The datetime index of sample_29m is a rolling windows  
sample_29m = data.resample('29min').agg({
    'open': 'first',
    'high': 'max',
    'low': 'min',
    'close': 'last',
})
```

Another example:

```python
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df= [[192, 203, 188, 193],
     [195, 201, 178, 196],
     [196, 210, 182, 201],
     [199, 211, 198, 203],
     [201, 221, 197, 212],
     [203, 218, 195, 209]]

data = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['open', 'high', 'low', 'close'], 
                  index=[
                      datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 11, 8, 57, 32),
                      datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 11, 9, 13, 12),
                      datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 11, 9, 25, 8),
                      datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 11, 9, 32, 56),
                      datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 11, 9, 42, 32),
                      datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 11, 10, 2, 11)                      
                  ])
sample_30m = data.resample('30min').agg({
    'open': 'first',
    'high': 'max',
    'low': 'min',
    'close': 'last',
})
sample_29m = data.resample('29min').agg({
    'open': 'first',
    'high': 'max',
    'low': 'min',
    'close': 'last',
})
```

Comment: Maybe I'm out of my depth, but I don't understand the question. Resampling to 30 minutes would downsample, but a rolling 30 minute window wouldn't, so which one is it? My best guess is you're trying to ask how to align the resample window to the end instead of the start. It'd be a lot easier to tell with a [reproducible pandas example](/q/20109391/4518341), meaning some example data, desired output, and actual output. You can [edit] to add that and clarify if needed. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: Thanks. I make a code to show the difference

Answer (score -1):

```
## another example
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df= [[192, 203, 188, 193],
     [195, 201, 178, 196],
     [196, 210, 182, 201],
     [199, 211, 198, 203],
     [201, 221, 197, 212],
     [203, 218, 195, 209]]

data = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['open', 'high', 'low', 'close'], 
                  index=[
                      datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 11, 8, 57, 32),
                      datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 11, 9, 13, 12),
                      datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 11, 9, 25, 8),
                      datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 11, 9, 32, 56),
                      datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 11, 9, 42, 32),
                      datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 11, 10, 2, 11)                      
                  ])
sample_30m = data.resample('30min').agg({
    'open': 'first',
    'high': 'max',
    'low': 'min',
    'close': 'last',
})
sample_29m = data.resample('29min').agg({
    'open': 'first',
    'high': 'max',
    'low': 'min',
    'close': 'last',
})**strong text**
```

Comment: In sample_30m, the time index is 08:30,  09:00,  0930, 10:00.
--

In sample_29m, the time index is 08:42,  09:11, 09:40
---------------
it's the rule behind 30min and 29min is difference.
I how my latest data in reshape should be the end of  row. In my data, the last entry is 10:02:11 . I hope the last row in the reshape is   9:34-10:03

Comment: Same here. Please edit this into your question, not as an answer.